# Nested Batch Structure execution gets terminated

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a nested batch structure. First I start with X.cmd which calls X1.cmd and then X2.cmd. But it is required that X2.cmd must start exactly after X1.cmd has done with its job.

Currently, after the execution of  X1.cmd, it does not continue with X2.cmd. I guess it is because of the "start" statement. (seems like it destroys the parent window.) In order to solve this problem. I changed the structure and made X2.cmd called inside X1.cmd. However this time the problem is: X2.cmd starts before tst10.exe finishes its job and it is useless for me. (It is pretty logical though. Because X1.cmd finishes the execution of first 4 lines by calling tst10.exe and continues by calling X2.cmd. But it is useless for me since I need tst10.exe to finish its job)

I need to be able to detect that tst10.exe finished its job, its windows is terminated and then I must call X2.cmd. How can I do that?

Here is the structure I want to use: (X2.cmd must do its job after tst10.exe finished its job)

***X.cmd***

```
X1.cmd
X2.cmd
```

***X1.cmd***

```
start tst10.exe /r:a.txt /o:a.txt
start tst10.exe /r:b.txt /o:b.txt
start tst10.exe /r:c.txt /o:c.txt
start tst10.exe /r:d.txt /o:d.txt
```

***X2.cmd***

```
start K.cmd
start L.cmd
start M.cmd
start N.cmd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**x.cmd**

```
call x1.cmd
call x2.cmd
```

**x1.cmd**

```
start tst10.exe /r:a.txt /o:a.txt
start tst10.exe /r:b.txt /o:b.txt
start tst10.exe /r:c.txt /o:c.txt
start tst10.exe /r:d.txt /o:d.txt

:testloop
    tasklist | find "tst10.exe" >nul || exit /b 0
    ping -n 2 localhost > nul
    goto testloop
```

**x2.cmd**

```
call K.cmd
call L.cmd
call M.cmd
call N.cmd
```

Without the `call`, execution is transfered to the called batch file and does not return to the caller.

Comment: @Xentius, Sorry, doing 3 things at the same time and posted an incomplete answer.

Comment: @Xentius, x2 will be executed when x1 finishes and execution returns to the caller (x.cmd) to continue.

Comment: @Xentius, i will change the answer, but you have not indicated the tst10 processes should be concurrent.

Comment: @Xentius, updated. `ping` is being used to include a delay. You can use also `timeout /t 1` if available in you OS.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. One last thing maybe you should edit: I needed to use start rather than call in X2.cmd (start K.cmd start L.cmd etc.) My OS supports timeout /t 1 but which one is more efficient you think? timeout or ping?

Comment: also I could not really understand the reason why we used ping or timeout. Could you please explain it? Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Xentius, if batch files called from x2.cmd are concurrent, then, of course, do not use call. To wait for test10 to end, a loop is defined. While the program is in the list of tasks, keep looping. The ´ping´ or ´timeout´ just add a delay between each check. Timeout is not included in XP, so ping is a usual replacement.

Answer (score 1):

only use start with wait parameter in x.cmd to start for X1.cmd. 
like that: 
X.cmd
start /wait X1.cmd